# How to programatically "yank the network cable" in a large Linux application?

Tags: c++, linux, networking, filesystems

I have a large C++ application on Linux with many first party and third party libraries built and linked against.

There are certain parts of the application that should execute without accessing the filesystem or network (particularly to load networked files). Periodically we find that this operation does indeed load files usually due to programmer error.

How can I enforce this with in the code? For example something like:

```
try {
  lockFileSystem();
  Application->DoImportantOperation();
  unlockFileSystem();
} catch ( InvalidFileSystemAccess )
{ 
 // bad programmer, no pizza
}
```

Or alternatively is there some sort of lower level callback that the app can hook when a file is opened?

Note I'm aware of the awesomeness of strace, but its gotten to the point where this needs to be enforced as part of the application execution, not as post-hoc manual test.

Comment: *How* does it load files? Could you just refrain from `#including <fstream>`?

Comment: The loading is not enforceable at compile time. The application is essentially running a script, and some parts should not access the file system.

Comment: launch the application in a chroot? setup some iptables rules to deny the application access to your file server? setup a SELinux policy? do not allow access to the mountpoint to the user the application runs as? run the application in its own network namespace / VRF domain? ...

Comment: The key here is "programatically" - that is the program should have enough introspection to be able to detect this case, rather than forcing the user modify the environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what exactly the code is legitimately trying to do, but you could possibly do this with `setrlimit()`'s `RLIMIT_NOFILE`.

Something like this should work:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

struct scoped_fd_blocker {
    rlim_t prev;
    scoped_fd_blocker() {
        rlimit lim;
        getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim); // get the current limit
        prev = lim.rlim_cur; // save old limit
        lim.rlim_cur = 0; // set the soft limit to 0
        setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim); // do the set
    }

    ~scoped_fd_blocker() {
        rlimit lim;
        getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim); // get the current limit
        lim.rlim_cur = prev; // reset the soft limit to the previous value
        setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &lim); // do the set
    }
};


// Example Usage:
void do_stuff() {
    scoped_fd_blocker blocker;
    Application->DoImportantOperation();
}
```

Basically this tells the OS not to let your process open any *file descriptor*, even if an existing one is closed, by zeroing the soft open file descriptor limit of the process.  Note that this is more than just files and could have some unintended consequences.  This would include files, sockets, event objects, directories, shared resources, pipes, and would also prevent C-libraries from opening files.  (Some C libraries do use file locks and stuff to manage concurrency.)  Think about all of the things that open files (like `dlopen` for example).

Any attempt to open a file descriptor will fail (return -1) and errno will be set to `EMFILE` which translates to "Error 24: Too many open files".

I've put the whole thing in a struct so that it's strongly exception safe.

Comment: This looks promising. Reading this, http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit I can't tell if calling `setrlimit` would require super-user privileges. I imagine not, as its being called within the same process.

Comment: @Justicle raising rlim_max above what is returned by getrlimit would require root privs.  Messing with rlim_cur does not (but it can't go above rlim_max).  This also means if you lower rlim_max you can't raise it again.

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant, but you can hook for example open() and route it through your own proxy_open() type call which has state. If state is "no file system allowed!" then you simply return the appropriate error and/or handle it however you like.